# Is anybody maintaining leafpad?

Tags: editors

I'm using Leafpad as the plain-and-simple text editor on my Devuan GNU/Linux. But - I've noticed the Copyright message is from 2010, and the [homepage](http://tarot.freeshell.org/leafpad/) also suggests no recent releases.

I wanted to file a bug against it and there didn't seem to be anywhere I could do so.

Is it actually maintained anywhere, or is it abandoned?

Comment: I think you'll find the spiritual successor is 'FeatherPad', which is actually pretty solid and has some great features. It's the new default in Lubuntu, for example. In fact, in the 20.04 release of Lubuntu it's only in the repos as a part of the LXDE-meta package.

Comment: Featherpad worked just fine in LXDE, if that's what you're asking. It should work just fine for you in Devuan, though I've never tested. They're not the same, and I don't think the same people are involved in both, thus 'spiritual successor' was how I described it. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @KGIII: But featherpad is in Qt and leafpad is in GTK. So... shouldn't they just be developed as a single project with a build-configuration option to choose between the two graphical toolkits?

Comment: @A.B: Edited my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The project I believe is what you would call feature complete but bug reports and feature ideas/updates are excepted at there github https://github.com/tarot231/leafpad

Comment: Are they though? No issues have ever been closed on the GH repo, and no PRs have ever been submitted, let alone merged.

Comment: @StephenKitt: To be fair, only 2 issues had been filed before I just filed 3 of mine. On the other hand - those two issues have not seen any comments, despite one of them being about 1.5 years old.

Comment: Yes; my point is really that there’s very little indication that “bug reports and feature ideas/updates are accepted”.

Comment: I think the best way to look at this is as a complete project it’s a text editor not every project needs to keep growing and growing.  You may want to contact them and see about helping with the project.  But again that is there decision if they want to keep the project as is.

Comment: @JasonCroyle: But it's not complete if its existing features have bugs. Or if there are missing aspects of behavior persistence which do not involve UI changes.

Comment: There is always going to be bugs its complete when the bugs exist don't effect the operation of the program there are two "issues" open now one looks like a one off and the other appears to be a well know bug that appears to be coming from one of the librarys there using.  What should they be doing?  There is always another option fork the project and support the "features" you want.

Comment: @Jason we can’t tell the project what it should be doing. What I’m saying is that you shouldn’t write that “bug reports and feature ideas/updates are accepted” unless you *know* that they really are. You can’t write that in your answer and then argue that the project doesn’t have to in the comments...

Comment: There are "two" open issues "two" for a project that has been around for what a decade open your issues which are more of feature requests not issues by the way and see what happens.  You can't say a project is abandoned because the devs feel that one issue which appears to be a one off problem could be user error or mis configuration and the other open issue is a know bug from a library.  What else could they be doing?  I don't mean this as an attack or anything I am really interested what else could they do?